# hawtio-web stuck "deploying", won't start in karaf

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, hawtio

( hawtio version 1.4.27, karaf version 3.0.2 )

i'm not quite sure what i'm missing here. I ran the following console commands to deploy the hawtio feature to Karaf

```
karaf@local()> feature:repo-add mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.4.27/xml/features 
Adding feature url mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.4.27/xml/features
karaf@local()> feature:install hawtio-core
karaf@local()> web:list
ID  | State       | Web-State   | Level | Web-ContextPath | Name                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
216 | Active      | Deploying   | 80    | /hawtio         | hawtio :: hawtio-web (1.4.27)
karaf@local()>
```

As suggested [here](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1568) i'm installing only the hawtio-core feature.

however, the war bundle 207 ( hawtio-web ) is forever stuck in the "Deploying" web-state. I don't see any servlets installed either

```
karaf@local()> http:list
ID | Servlet | Servlet-Name | State | Alias | Url
-------------------------------------------------
karaf@local()>
```

According to log:display ( the root logger is running on INFO and logging to osgi:* ) these are the only relevant lines logged

```
2014-10-22 16:09:17,783 | WARN  | e ssh user karaf | FeatureValidationUtil            | 24 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 3.0.1 | Old style feature file without namespace found (URI: mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.4.27/xml/features). This format is deprecated and support for it will soon be removed
2014-10-22 16:10:03,770 | INFO  | e ssh user karaf | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 24 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 3.0.1 | Installing feature hawtio-core 1.4.27
2014-10-22 16:10:03,771 | INFO  | e ssh user karaf | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 24 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 3.0.1 | Installing feature war 3.0.1
```

Any ideas on how i could debug this, as nothing indicating a problem is logged, the war is "stuck" and the /hawtio resource is not available?

thanks!
Andras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PBKAC - i had org.osgi.core and org.osgi.compendium downloaded by maven and added to the karaf "lib" folder. They creeped on to the classpath ( definitely not listed in -cp though ) - as karaf/felix provide the packages in these, they are redundant and apparently cause extremely difficult to debug problems ( again, not a single line logged indicating a problem )

tl;dr this is not reproducible with the 3.0.2 karaf release tar. Drop osgi.core and osgi.compendium in the lib folder however..